# Special characters \{ and \} in mtpro2

Tags: characters, braces, mtpro

I recently just started running into a special character error for curly braces,  like { and } in the example below:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{times}
 \usepackage[complete,subscriptcorrection,mtpcal,mtphrb]{mtpro2} 
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \begin{document}

       \{ 1 \}

 \end{document}
```

for which the error message is:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.11 \{
        1 \}
?
```

Comment: With just this code in a document the error does not occur, therefore the problem must be somewhere else. Could you try to produce a minimal example that actually reproduces this error?

Comment: please always post a complete small document that shows the error. Presumably some code you have not shown has redefined `\{` to be math-only.

Comment: See updated question, the error is simply being thrown because of mtpro2.  If i comment out mtpro2, the error doesn't occur.

Comment: Off-topic: \usepackage{times} is depreciated. You can use \usepackage{newtxtext} a clone of Times new roman.

Comment: Thanks but that's not the solution, as the error occurs from mtpro2.  I think the characters { and } are not being found.

Comment: Something redefined them in math mode only.

Comment: Can that be done erroneously, or does it have to be done specifically?   I never purposely enforced any special character to be math-mode.   If it can be done erroneously, what kind of code example would render \{ and \} to be math.mode?

Comment: @wrktsj I show the code that `mtpro.sty` used in my answer. In this case, the definition used a plain TeX command only valid in math mode, but breaking the command in text mode was probably unintended.

Comment: Okay - TeX is beyond me, although I did learn a lot of the \Biggl( type commands from the TeX book ages ago.

Comment: And it looks like this bug has been around for at least eight years. It’s reassuring that @egreg solved it the exact same way in 2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mtpro2` package redefines `\{` and `\}` as:

```
\def\curlybraces{\def\lbrace{\delimiter"4266308 }\let\{=\lbrace
  \def\rbrace{\delimiter"5267309 }\let\}=\rbrace}
```

Where `\delimiter` is a TeX primitive, `"4266308` means class 4 (`\mathopen`), the small form is math family 2, slot `"66` (hexadecimal), and the large form is math family 3, slot `"08`, and likewise for the closing delimiter in class 5.

What’s relevant to you here is that this is a definition for math mode and math mode only.  Therefore, when you try to use it in text mode, you get an error message saying that you forgot a `$` somewhere.

The LaTeX kernel does define the text-mode commands `\textbraceleft` and `\textbraceright` with`\DeclareTextSymbol`. These should still be valid, but you can if necessary `\UndeclareTextCommand` and then redefine them as:

```
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textbraceleft}{T1}{"7B}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textbraceright}{T1}{"7D}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textbraceleft}{\UnicodeEncodingName}{"78}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textbraceright}{\UnicodeEncodingName}{"7D}
\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\textbraceleft}{T1}
\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\textbraceright}{T1}
```

Therefore, you can use this workaround:

```
\def\{{\ifmmode\lbrace\else\textbraceleft\fi}
\def\}{\ifmmode\rbrace\else\textbraceright\fi}
```

Which uses the correct command in either math mode or text mode.  I don’t know if the package is still being actively maintained, but breaking `\{` and `\}` in text mode should be considered a bug.

Comment: Thanks, and thanks to all those who commented.  I'll try coding these up and then get back.   I think everyone and @David Carlisle were correct in stating \{ had to be defined in math-only; however, why all of a sudden the error now, when it didn't do it for several years? Also, \{ is common in text, so why would mtpro developers recode this?

Comment: @wrktsj Sounds like a package update broke it.

Comment: Using the last two lines of code resolved the issue - many thanks!

Comment: Very nice answer that I am very happy to vote up.:-)